# Unique value from the arraylist

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have a Array List with array of objects. The object has 2 values. One is Question and another one is answer. There is a possibility of same answer for n number of questions. In other words, there are duplicates at Answer level. I want to draw 5 objects from the array list whose answers are entirely different.

Could you please guide me with some techniques ?

```
ArrayList<ToughQuiz> animalQuizCollection;

    animalQuizCollection  = new ArrayList<ToughQuiz>(); 
    for(int i=0; i<animalQuestionCount;i++){  
        toughQuiz =  new ToughQuiz(animalQuestion[i], animalAnswer[i]);  
        animalQuizCollection.add(toughQuiz);     
    }
```

Comment: use a Set<Answer>, and check that the answer of the current element is not already in the set. If not, add it to the result and to the set, and continue the loop, until you have 5 elements in your result.

Comment: This is enough to get started. Use the documentation, experiment. That's how you'll learn.

Comment: use a map instead of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Set<Answer> answersSet = new HashSet<Answer>();
List<ToughQuiz> differentAnswers = new ArrayList<ToughQuiz>();
for(ToughQuiz quiz : animalQuizCollection){
    if(answersSet.add(quiz.getAnswer())){
        differentAnswers.add(quiz);
    }
    if(differentAnswers.size() >= 5) break;
}
```

`Answer` in your case could be just a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop to verify that the answer is not in your ArrayList

```
ArrayList<ToughQuiz> animalQuizCollection;
boolean find=false;
    animalQuizCollection  = new ArrayList<ToughQuiz>(); 
    for(int i=0; i<animalQuestionCount;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<animalQuizCollection ; j++) {
             if(animalAnswer[i].equals( animalQuizCollection.get(j).getAnswer() ) {
                   find = true;
                   break;
             }
             else
                  find = false;
        }
        if(!find) {   
            toughQuiz =  new ToughQuiz(animalQuestion[i], animalAnswer[i]);
            animalQuizCollection.add(toughQuiz);  
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<AminalAnswer, AnimalQuestion> animalQuizCollection;

animalQuizCollection = new HashMap<>(); //diamond operator for java 7 only.
int randomIndex;
Random random = new Random();
while(animalQuizCollection.size() < 5){  
    randomIndex = random.nextInt(animalAnswer.length);  
    animalQuizCollection.put(animalAnswer[randomIndex], animalQuestion[randomIndex]);
}  

for(AnimalAnswer answer : animalQuizCollection.keySet()) {
    // you will have 5 unique answers here and animalQuizCollection.get(answer)
    // will get you the question that corresponds to it
}
```

This is kind of a quick and dirty approach and could be made more efficient especially with the randoms. However it will basically randomly chose answers and questions and add them to a map where answer is the key until the map get 5 entries.

I haven't tested this so there might be bugs but the concept seems solid.

Answer (score 0):

make a Comparator for comparing the ThoughQuestion

```
public class ToughQuizAnswerComparator implements Comparator<ToughQuiz> { 
    @Override 
    public int compare(ToughQuiz o1, ToughQuiz o2) { 
        return o1.getAnswer().compareTo(o2.getAnswer()); 
    } 
}
```

loop thru the ToughQuiz:

```
for (ToughQuiz q : toughQuizs)
```

make a new list, while you loop the first list, add to the first list if the element does not already exists, check by using the Collections class.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `equals` method in `ToughQuiz` that it returns same value for the same answer, i.e. calculate it using the answer.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || !(o instanceof ToughQuiz))
        return false;

    ToughQuiz other= (ToughQuiz) o;
    if (this.answer.equals(other.answer))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Then, you get five quizes like this:

```
Random random= new Random();
List<ToughQuiz> result= new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    //loop infinitely to find the unique answer 
    for (;;) {
        ToughQuiz quiz = animalQuizCollection.get(random.nextInt(animalQuizCollection.size());
        //because you overriden equals this will produce true if there is already an element inside with the same hashCode
        if (!result.contains(quiz)) {
            result.add(quiz);
            break; //break the inner loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A map will keep track of corresponding questions for you and has unique keys:

```
Map<Answer, ToughQuiz> map = new HashMap<>();  

for(ToughQuiz tq : animalQuizCollection)
    map.put(tq.getAnswer(), tq);
```

Now *map* contains all unique answers and their corresponding quizes.